# load div with click function from same page and replace with other div which is already load

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

i have a page where i add two div like div1 and div2 
i want to stop load div2 on page load and create a button in div1 which will load div to in place or div1 or replace it with div1.
this code work but it load both div and replace on click but i want to load it on click .

```
<span class="ecf-answer" id="div1">Content here</span>

<div id="div2">Content taken from the span element</div>

<button onclick="document.getElementById('div2').innerHTML = document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML">Teleport!!!</button>
```

Comment: `<span class="ecf-answer" id="div1">Content here</span>

<div id="div2">Content taken from the span element</div>

<button onclick="document.getElementById('div2').innerHTML = document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML">Teleport!!!</button>`

Comment: From what I understand, you want your page to show div1 and the button, and when the button is clicked, the content of div1 is replaced by what's inside div2, is that correct? If so you can just hide (display:none) div2 in your css

Comment: Right , i use the code as you say but i want load only div1 on page load and load div2 on click event not as you say load both and hide div2 then replace it on click event... is there way to stop load a div and on click event load a div and replace with other div..?

Comment: if you really don't want div2 to be present at all in your html before the click, I think you will need to fetch its content from an external source (an ajax request, for example)

Comment: An alternative, if you're ok with div2 briefly flashing in your html could be to add it hidden, and once the page is loaded, remove it using javascript and store its content in a variable

Comment: So you want to say that it's not possible to load a div after click event from same page.?

Answer (score 1):

Initially show `div1` and button but hide `div2` with the help of CSS `display:none`. Create a function like `copyContent` and listen when the button is clicked.

In `copyContent()` copy the content of `div1` and set it to `div2`, at the same time show the `div2` with style property to `block`.

```js
function copyContent() {
    const div2 = document.getElementById('div2')
    div2.innerText = document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML
    div2.style.display = 'block'
}
```

```html
<span class="ecf-answer" id="div1">Content here</span>

<div id="div2" style="display: none;">Content taken from the span element</div>

<button onclick="copyContent()">Teleport!!!</button>
```

Comment: downvoter: please explain the reason. Is this not helpful?

Comment: My mistake :)  ?

Comment: Initially `div2` is hidden. I think OP wanted to show the `div2` when the button is clicked.

Comment: Not only show after clicked i also want to load it after clicked.